# Loopback: Cannot call Notification.create(). The create method has not been setup. The PersistedModel has not been correctly attached to a DataSource

Tags: node.js, push-notification, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using Loopback and the push component.  When calling `Notification.create()` I get the error:

```
Cannot call Notification.create(). The create method has not been setup. 
The PersistedModel has not been correctly attached to a DataSource!
```

I'm just running the basic example server 2.0.  In code I am trying to create a Notification.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I too got the same problem when trying to use login function of User model.
Got it fixed after an hour of hit and trial.

**Answer:** I extended **User** model to **MyUser** model (No coding inside this model, just used it as a wrapper) and inside **Hotel.js** (in my case a business class where i use to authenticate user before accessing hotel details) created a remoteMethod for login

> **code:**

```
Hotel.auth=function(uname,pwd, cb)
    {
        Hotel.app.models.MyUser.login({username: uname, password: pwd}, function (err, token) {
            if(err)
                cb(null,err);
            else
                cb(null,token);
        });
    }

    Hotel.remoteMethod(
        'auth', 
        {
           accepts: 
          [
          {arg: 'uname', type: 'string',required: true},
          {arg: 'pwd', type: 'string',required: true}
          ],
          returns: {arg: 'Response Message', type: 'string'}
        }
    );
```

This works!

Answer (score 0):

This one is pretty old, but just to put something up here. Without seeing your setup my guess is that the model you are using is not connected to any data source, or one that is not written properly. The default connector is in-memory and does implement this method correctly. Check your `server/model-config.json` file and find the entry for `Notification` and check what you have for the data source.